# Импортирование проекта libGDX

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить вот эту проблему: при импортировании проекта libGDX, я так понял, отказывается брать библиотеку в IDE eclipse(ubuntu). SDK настроен и подключен.

[image: Представлен скрин проблемы]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте удалить кеш - `/home/username/.m2`

И дайте вывод ошибок, а не скрин. Также Java Development Kit должен бить версии 7 и выше

---

Или может у вас не установлен градл?

Если да, то без него никак, делайте по инструкции ниже:

В Eclipse нажмите

> Help -> Install New Software...

В поле "Work with:" вставьте http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle
[image: Gradle IDE]

После чего нажмите Установите, и так далее:

Work with: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
[image: Android Developer Tools]

Work with: https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4
[image: Google web Toolkit SDK]

После чего импортируйте проект так:
[image: Eclipse - Import libGDX]

Answer (score 0):

Если используешь *gradle*, то пропиши правильно репозитории в нем для *badlogic*'овских библиотек.

Попробуй очистить проект, и ребилдить его заново.